# Setting Secret Key in google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sftp

I need to sftp into an amazon ec2 instance to send files from data farmed from a firestore data base.  I'm trying to open the connection but I need to have access to the ec2 secret key file in the cloud functions.

I've done slightly similar things such as with stripe and the secret key so I believe this should be possible.  How do I upload my secret key file so I can have access to in the function below?

```
return sftp.connect({
    host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    port: 'xxxx',
    username: 'xxxxxx',
    privatekey: 'filepath'
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply put the secret key in the main directory and read it into the environment with

```
var privateKey = require('fs').readFileSync('./xxxxxxx.pem', {'encoding':'utf8'});
```

I may ask another question later to see if this is secure but I don't see why not.